# is client thread-safe in Twitter Finagle

Tags: scala, twitter-finagle

Is the the client in Twitter Finagle thread-safe ? 
I don't want to call newClient in each RPC function (I think it will make a new connection to destination end, is it?) So it seems that re-using the same client object is a good choice. But, because the RPC functions may be called by diff threads at the same time, is it safe to use the same Finagle client object ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is client-specific. All clients exported by Finagle are thread-safe, but your own  clients may not be if you don't design them to be.

Comment: Thanks! I mean the clients exported by Finagle. I have read through the doc (http://twitter.github.io/finagle/guide/Clients.html),but cannot find any useful information about the thread-safe stuff.